# "Conflicting String creators: already had explicitly marked ..."; where are the creators explicitly marked?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm new to Jackson and I'm seeing these errors when trying to deserialize a POJO with ObjectMapper.readValue:

> Conflicting String creators: already had explicitly marked [method CLASSNAME#fromString(1 params)], encountered [method CLASSNAME#valueOf(1 params)]

Both fromString and valueOf are static factory methods with the same signature.

I can't easily remove one or the other because dependencies are already using both, although for the code path I'm testing, it does work if I just remove valueOf. As mentioned though, I'd prefer if this weren't the permanent solution.

Neither method is annotated with @JsonCreator, and adding @JsonCreator and annotating the arguments properly yields the same error.

Since I can't see how either function is explicitly marked (because the only way I know is @JsonCreator), why is this error occurring, or where else could they be "explicitly marked"? Is it possible to still have both but then only use one for deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out the answer to my first question, but I managed to answer the second question by adding varargs to my second function and fail-safing with an exception that doesn't actually let a user add extra arguments. This is just to change the method signature.

Before:

```
public static String fromString(String arg) throws Exception { ... }
public static String valueOf(String arg) throws Exception { ... }
```

After:

```
public static String fromString(String arg) throws Exception { ... }
public static String valueOf(String arg, Object... varargs) throws Exception {
    if (varargs.length > 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't use these");
    }
...
}
```